# Build a node user access control management module that works with MySQL and express as middleware

Tags: mysql, node.js, authorization, middleware, user-management

I have to build an authorization module that allows user to use some functionality.  in Node I'm using express and mysql with sequelize as ORM. I don't have roles, but only users table and permissions table from mysql db:

**Users example (in js version)**

```
users = [
{ userid: "1",
  username: "arthur",
  password: "excalibur"
},
{ userid: "2",
  username: "merlin",
  password: "occhetipoccheti"
},
{ userid: "1",
  username: "morgana",
  password: "imnotevil"
}]
```

**Permissions**

```
permissions = [
{ permissionid: "1",
  action: "create",
  description: "create a file"
},
{ permissionid: "2",
  action: "read",
  description: "reada file"
},
{ permissionid: "3",
  action: "delete",
  description: "delete a file"
},
{ permissionid: "4",
  action: "update",
  description: "update a file"
}]
```

My purpose is to create a module, and using it as express middleware. I lack of design patterns for this job (i'm a front-end devguy), and I've tried a lot of npm package ([accesscontrol](https://www.npmjs.com/package/accesscontrol), [acl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl), [connect-roles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-roles) etc.), but now I want to create my own code, since I don't need role based authorisation, but instead a simple check through a third table that matches user and permission ids:

**Users_Permissions**

```
users_permissions = [
{ userid: "1",
  permissionid: "3"
},
{ userid: "1",
  permissionid: "2"
},
{ userid: "2",
  permissionid: "1"
},
{ userid: "3",
  permissionid: "1"
},
{ userid: "3",
  permissionid: "3"
},]
```

I have read some topics like these: [Node JS and Access Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086317/node-js-and-access-control),
[Users management in node js with express, mongodb as server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291137/users-management-in-node-js-with-express-mongodb-as-server-database)

but the many of these is focusing on roles and I do not need role... How can I do? Can Someone help me with a tutorial link maybe? I want to know the best way to design a module in node.

Basically the function I want to build is

**example module.can**

```
can(userId, permissionid) {
  users_permissions.forEach(element => {
    if (userId == element.userid) {
      if (element.permissionid == permissionid) {
        console.log('true');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Thx you
Pasquale